# Display message each time SQL update is successful

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I'm using PHP to update my item table based on a result set.

```
while (!$rs->EOF) { 
    $conn->Execute("UPDATE [table] SET qty='".$quantity."' WHERE 
            locn ='".$locn."' AND pdln ='".$pdln."'");

    echo "Item updated...<br/>";  /////////Message display here

    $rs->MoveNext();                
}
```

Because the volume of data is pretty large, I wanted a message to be displayed to the user after each successful update one row at a time. Is there a way to achieve this using Ajax or Jquery?

Comment: this can work as long as output buffering is off, but the long loading time on browser could annoy you

Comment: Do you want to send a message to a browser saying that it has updated? Please explain whether this is when the page is initially loading or the page has loaded and this is a response to an ajax request

Comment: if my understanding is right, try having a look at [Html5 server sent events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

while (!$rs->EOF) { 
$conn->Execute("UPDATE [table] SET qty='".$quantity."' WHERE 
     locn ='".$locn."' AND pdln ='".$pdln."'");
    echo "Item updated...<br/>";  /////////Message display here
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);

    $rs->MoveNext();                
} 
echo "Done.";
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: hi, execute query in mysql return a boolean result. True on success or False on error.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. See comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding

```
while (!$rs->EOF) { 
    $conn->Execute("UPDATE [table] SET qty='".$quantity."' WHERE 
            locn ='".$locn."' AND pdln ='".$pdln."'");

    echo TRUE;  // You can return False if row didn't update if you want

    $rs->MoveNext();                
}
```

And in your HTML, use the jQuery function `.ajax()` or use Javascript.

```
   $.ajax
   ({
    url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/site/bookmark/"+$bookmark_button.parent().attr('id'),
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data)
    {

      switch ( data )
      {
        case TRUE:
           console.log('Item updated successfully '); // Change the way it's displayed as you like
          break;
        case FALSE:
           console.log('Item did not update successfully '); // Change the way it's displayed as you like
        break;
      }

    },
    error: function(data)
    {
      console.log('Error updating item, connection error maybe?'); // Optional
    }
  });
```